# Implies cannot find an answer

Tags: logic

I have a simple relation and I try to find if P implies Q or not. I expect to get True because it is somehow obvious for me.

```
P1 = j == i && j < 0 && t >= -j
Q = t>0
FullSimplify[ Reduce[ForAll[{i, j, t}, Implies[ P1 , Q]]]]
```

When I run this I get an echo, which means cannot solve it.

**But When I remove j == i ,** it returns `True`.

can someone explain me why and what is the solution? I am fine to use other functions, I just need to check if P implies Q or not.

```
P2 = j < 0 && t >= -j
Q = t > 0
FullSimplify[ForAll[{i, j, t}, Implies[P2, Q]]]

True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `Reals` domain helps (By default, variables are assumed as complexes.).

```
P1 = j == i && j < 0 && t >= -j;Q = t > 0;
Resolve[ForAll[{i, j, t}, Implies[P1, Q]], Reals]
Reduce[ForAll[{i, j, t}, Implies[P1, Q]], Reals]
```

> `True` `True`

Comment: Thanks, it was great . But do you mean Complex Numbers? a + i*b? it's very interesting.

Comment: @Azzurro94: Yes, I do mean complex numbers.